# flutter_blue shows mac address instead of Names

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I am running flutter_blue example,it doesn't raise any error but after searching for bluetooth devices it shows mac address instead of Local Names.alse after clicking on connect it doesn't connect.

[image]

I did make sure that other devices are ble support, even I purchased Bluetooth v4.0 usb dongle to be completely sure about Bluetooth version, but nothing changed.
also, I thought it may be related to my android phone,I reset(factory) the phone and wiped cache but nothing changed.

my cellphone is Sony Xperia Z3+ with android 7.1.1;

any Idea what is wrong and why I can't get devices name in scan?

Answer (score 0):

It was gattserver, couldn't broadcast properly,I changed gattServer with another app in another smartphone and now it shows the Name of GattServer.

Comment: Could you please explain more about the solution?